# Can I click on a div in VBA?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation

I have the following HTML code that I am trying to click:

```
<div class="ListItems" style="top: 0px;">
  <div class="sf-element-list-box-item sfpc-selected" style="top: 0px; 
   height: 15px; line-height: 15px; width: 192px;" title="(All) 7 values">
   (All) 7 values</div>
  <div class="sf-element-list-box-item" style="top: 15px; height: 15px; 
   line-height: 15px; width: 192px;" title="A">A</div>
  <div class="sf-element-list-box-item" style="top: 30px; height: 15px; 
   line-height: 15px; width: 192px;" title="C">C</div>
  <div class="sf-element-list-box-item" style="top: 45px; height: 15px; 
   line-height: 15px; width: 192px;" title="D">D</div>
```

I am now trying to click on the list item D. I have tried in several different ways, but I am not sure if I am actually able to click on a div.

I tried this first:

```
Set tags = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")

     For Each tagx In tags
        If tagx.innerHTML = "D" Then
            tagx.Click
        End If
    Next
```

Since that didn't work I tried this:

```
For Each x In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")
            If x.Title = "D" Then


                x.parentElement.Click
            Exit For

        End If
    Next
```

I have found that I cannot use .title, .InnerText, or .innerHTML. Does anyone know of a way that I would be able to click or select the list item if it is a div? I don't believe that I am getting into the IF statement, meaning the .click never executes.

Comment: Do either of the "click" lines execute?  You need to do a little debugging and give us a bit more information here.

Comment: @TimWilliams The click lines do execute, but for some reason it doesn't actually work.

Comment: Can you click the "D" directly on the page using the mouse, or do you first have to click something else?  It's difficult to make any suggestions without the context of the rest of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can do this over the `fireEvent` in vba:

```
tagx.FireEvent "onclick"
```

this is the way to trigger an event in vba.

EDIT: And sure you can use `innerHTML` and `innerText`. The returned elemnts implements the IHTMLElement interface. You can take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279(v=vs.85).aspx) which properties are supported.